# How to handle child event in parent control

Tags: wpf, events, event-handling, routes, event-bubbling

In my main window, I have a child control(user control) which contains a text box . How can I handle the textchange event of the text box of child control in main(parent) window.

Please provide me some example with code as I am new to routing of events.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should just be able to hook the event from the parent control. But since your parent control doesn't have a `TextChanged` event of its own, you'll need to use attached-property syntax:

```
<Window ...
        TextBox.TextChanged="ChildTextBoxChanged">
```

and in your codebehind:

```
private void ChildTextBoxChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ...
}
```

You don't have to put the `TextBox.TextChanged=` on the `Window` specifically -- just any control that's a parent of the `TextBox`, i.e., any control that's a parent of your `UserControl`. The event will bubble up to each parent in turn, all the way up to the top-level `Window`, and can get handled anywhere along the way.

(Note that if anyone hooks the event and sets `e.Handled = true`, the event won't bubble past that point. Useful to know if you have handlers at multiple levels.)

Comment: +1 - there is an example of how to declare the event here: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201209/Blog/WPF-Bubbling-A-Command-From-A-Child-View/

Comment: Will this creates 100 event handlers if there are 100 child `TextBox`? That might cause performance issue. What if there are 1000?

Answer (score 1):

this also helped me. I will have a event in the container of the child control and define the event in the code behind file. The event will handle all the text changed events for all the children.

```
       <StackPanel TextBoxBase.TextChanged="test_TextChanged" Name="test">                                    
                <userControl/>
       </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a event in your childcontrol -

```
public event TextChangedEventHandler TextChanged;
```

now add a handler for TextChanged event of TextBox in childcontrol -

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (TextChanged != null)
    {
        TextChanged.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

also update XAML for this handler -

```
<TextBox ... TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" ... />
```

Now, you have created a event in your childcontrol that fires when the Textbox's textchanged fires.

Now you only to add a handler for this event in mainwindow -

```
private void ChildControl_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
   //TODO: Add your further code here.
}
```